# Failed to switch from log4j to logback in Spring App

Tags: spring, log4j, logback

Currently, my spring app is using the import statement - '**org.apache.log4j.Logger**'. I want to change it to **logback** without changing the codebase. I tried with below dependencies along with a **logback.xml** config file.

```
<!-- SLF4J API -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.32</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Logback Classic -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<!-- log4j-over-slf4j bridge -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.32</version>
</dependency>
```

If anyone can come up with a solution to make it done, it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The dependencies look Ok. Check if you **don't** have `log4j:log4j` as (transitive?) dependency.